# Sending Email vb.Net Stoping program

Tags: vb.net, sendmail

I need help to make Visual Basic not stop while sending emails.
I am using `Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)` everytime it's sends an email the program stops for 5 seconds and then it's stop work for maybe 3 sec and then it sends the mail.

I want to be able to still use the program while it's sends the mail Help plz!

Comment: If you send many mails, go to MSDN and search for BackGroundWorker. If only one, go to MSDN and search on ThreadStart object. Examples are there. it is not complex

Comment: What is the type/class of `Smtp_Server`?  If it is `SmtpClient` you could use `SendAsync` or `SendMailAsync` to not block the calling thread, but can't tell from what you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some logging or careful observation in the debugger to confirm, but the conversation between your client and the SMTP server is probably taking 5 seconds (which is quite long, but plausible).

The solution is to use multiple threads to send email.

If you are sending batches of emails, try starting with 5-10 threads (with too many, the SMTP server on the other end might start rejecting some connection attempts).

If you are trying to send a single email at a time, but it is blocking your main application, you can use a single separate thread to perform the send.

Comment: Im kind of noob of Visual basic what do you mean with threads.
Im trying to send like one email every 15 min but I just don't want the program to be unuseable for ~7sec while sending it

Comment: Threads are a concept that allows your program to do more than one thing at a time.  Since you're trying to send 1 email every 15 minutes without blocking the app, you can create a single new thread to do the sending.  For an intro to threads, check out http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/threadingintro.htm